Sveltekit renders a different page than is specified in the URL after redirecting
I created a basic sveltekit application, in which a user can create an account and login to the application to change their data. Right now this is the only functionality besides a "forgot password" functionality implementation.
Something weird happens occasionally after logging out from the application. This does not happen every time, but often enough to matter.
After logging out, sveltekit sometimes renders a different page than is specified in the url. A log-out happens via deleting the session cookie and triggering a redirect.
However, sometimes the redirect is intended to go to the contact page, and the url also specifies this correctly (localhost/contact), but the actual page that is rendered is the login page. Even though the login page is at localhost/login.
I have not been able to identify a pattern to this behavior. Often times everything works as expected, but sometimes it doesnt. Also the pages that are misdirect change each time it doesnt work.
Anyone know why this is happening?
Edit:
Here is how I got my routes setup:

Here is how clicking a logout button logs a user out:
import { redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit"

/** @type {"import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions = {

    default: async ({cookies}) => {
        
        // get session ID
        const sessionID = cookies.get("sessionID");

        if(sessionID){
            cookies.delete("sessionID", { path: "/" });
            throw redirect(302,"/");
        } else {
            throw redirect(302,"/");
        }
    }
}

In this case the redirect is thrown to home ("/"). After navigating to contact:
http://localhost:5173/Contact
The page "Dashboard" is rendered, even though it is located at http://localhost:5173/Dashboard.

I have encountered this behavior with other pages as well, not always contact and dashboard.
The +layout.svelte file is coded like this:
<script>
    import Navbar from "./Navbar.svelte";
    import Footer from "./Footer.svelte";


    /** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
    export let data;
</script>
  
<div class="flex-container">

    <Navbar loggedIn = {data.isLoggedIn} />
    <div class="slot-container">
        <slot />
    </div>
    

    <div class="footer">
        <Footer />
    </div>    
</div>

and the +layout.server.js file is coded like this:
import { SESSION_LENGTH_MINUTES } from '$env/static/private';
import { user } from "../db/test_ML";


/** @type {import('./$types').LayoutServerLoad} */
export async function load({ cookies, url }) {

    // dummy. doing this to force the load function to repeat after automatic logout (after every navigation)
    console.log(url.pathname);

    // get session ID
    const sessionID = cookies.get("sessionID");
    var isLoggedIn = false;

    if(!sessionID){

        isLoggedIn = false;
    } else {
        const userObject = await user.findOne({Session_ID: sessionID}, {projection: {Session_Timestamp:1}});

        // check if session ID belongs to a user
        if(!userObject){
            
            isLoggedIn = false;

        } else { 

            // check if session ID is still valid
            const sessionDeadline = new Date(new Date(userObject["Session_Timestamp"]).getTime() + SESSION_LENGTH_MINUTES * 60000);
            const now = new Date();
            const sessionIsValid = new Date(now.getTime()) < sessionDeadline;

            if(!sessionIsValid){
                isLoggedIn = false;
            } else {
                
                isLoggedIn = true;

            }
            
        }
        

    }

    return {
        isLoggedIn,
    };
}


Please create a minimal reproduction and show all the relevant code.

hello @brunnerh, I have added some information. does this help?

That is not a suitable reproduction, it is neither minimal nor self-contained. Chances are that you would find the problem while reducing everything to a minimal reproduction - I don't see anything in the given code that could cause this and have never heard of someone having this issue before.

I have never encountered this behavior before either, but if it's a bug in the framework, then sometimes random things like can be fixed by simply updating the framework to the latest version, so you might want to consider trying that.

Your grouped routes (folders named (Like_This)) don't contain folders named Contact and Dashboard, right?

Thanks for the tips! My sveltekit and svelte versions are already up to date, so this shouldnt be the issue. I also dont have duplicate folder names anywhere.
Could this have anything to do with a cashing issue?  I dont specifically use any cashing, but since this issue does not happen regularly, it might not be due to an error in the code right?

I can't see how caching can cause an issue like this. When an error occurs only sometimes, then it's usually due to a race condition in my experience. In JavaScript, this would mean you have multiple asynchronous operations running at the same time, and usually they complete in the order you expect, and everything works fine, but sometimes they complete in an order you don't expect, and that's when the unexpected behavior appears.

But I still can't see how such an error can cause SvelteKit to show a page other than the one indicated by the URL. To me, it really sounds like it's a bug in SvelteKit. But strange that it has never happened to others as far as I know if that would be the case.
